# React: Table with backend elements does not re-render when clicking a NavLink in the NavBar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm doing a CRUDL for a vet-app in `react@18.2.0`, `react-router@6.8.1`. When I click a navBar element (i.e. pets) for the first time, it shows correctly the table with backend elements, which are individual JSON files for each object (a single pet/owner data) that are organized by entities on folders (i.e. ../data/pets/jsdnsj12.json), however, when I click another element on the navBar (i.e. owners) the table does not re-render/update with the correct backend elements until I refresh the page.

Note: `Page` is the reusable function that renders the elements (table, modal, actions menu) according to entities (i.e. pets, owners).

The /pets path renders a table that contains the info of registered pets. the columns of the table are pet name, pet owner and pet type (dog, cat, etc.). On the other hand, the /owners path shows the first/last name of the owner, and his ID document (driver's license, certificate of birth, etc.). When initially clicked, each entity shows data in the table correctly, but if you try to change to other path (i.e. from /pets to /owners, or viceversa), the table remains the same for the first entity data, it does not update to the corresponding new path/entity (unless you refresh the page).

**This is the App.js. Note: the `<RootLayout/>` integrates the `NavigationBar` and `Outlet` component from `react-router-dom`**

```
const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route path="/" element={<RootLayout />}>
      <Route
        key={"/pets"}
        path="pets"
        element={<Page title="Pets" entity="pets" />}
      />
      <Route
        key={"/owners"}
        path="owners"
        element={<Page title="Owners" entity="owners" />}
      />
    </Route>
  )
)

function App() {
  return (
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  );
}
```

Page.js

```
class Page extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showModal: false,
      entities: [],
      object: {},
      objectId: null,
      method: "POST",
      columns: [],
      options: initialOptions,
      search: '',
      vet: "",
      pet: "",
    };
  }

  /*
   * showEntity is supposed to re render the table as well, but
   * it only renders the actions menu
   */
  showEntity = async (_event = null) => {
    if (_event) {
      _event.preventDefault();
    }
    const { entity } = this.props;
    const { search, columns, vet, pet } = this.state;
    const entities = await listEntity({ entity, search, columns, vet, pet });
    let _columns = [];
    if (Array.isArray(entities) && entities.length > 0) {
      _columns = Object.keys(entities[0]).filter((col) => col !=="id") || [];
    }
    this.setState({ entities, columns: _columns });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const { entity } = this.props;
    if (entity === "owners") {
      this.getBackendOptions({});
      return;
    }
    this.showEntity();
  };

  /* 
   * Now, in render, the <ActionsMenu/> component does re render, 
   * which is expected, but the <Table/> component does not
   */

  render() {
    const { title = "unnamed", entity } = this.props;
    const {columns, objectId, entities, object, options} = this.state;
    return (
      <> 
        <ActionsMenu 
          changeModal={ this.changeModal } 
          title={title} 
          handleSearchInput={this.handleSearchInput}
          search={this.showEntity}
          entity={entity}   
          options={options} 
        />

        <Table 
          entities= {entities} 
          editEntity={this.editEntity}
          deleteEntity={this.deleteEntity}
          columns={columns}
        />
```

Table.js: table heade.
r and table row receives data of index and state, respectively

```
function Table({
  entities = [], 
  editEntity = () => {}, 
  deleteEntity = () => {}, 
  columns = [],   
}) {
  return (
    <table className="table table-stripped table-hover">
      <TableHeader columns={columns} />
      <tbody id="table-list">
        {entities.map((entity, index) => (
          <TableRow
            key={`row-${index}`} 
            index={entity.id ? entity.id : false} 
            entity={entity} 
            editEntity={editEntity} 
            deleteEntity={deleteEntity}
            columns={columns}
          />
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}
```

NavigationBar.js

```
function NavigationBar() {
  return (
    <>
      <input type="checkbox" id="check" />
      <nav className="navbar">
        <div className="icon"><b>P</b>ethical</div>
        <ul>
          <li className="nav-item">
            <NavLink className="nav-link" to={"/"} end>
              Home
            </NavLink>
          </li>
          <li className="nav-item active">
            <NavLink className="nav-link" to={'/pets'} end>
              Pets
            </NavLink>
          </li>
          <li className="nav-item">
            <NavLink className="nav-link" to={'/owners'} end>
              Owners
            </NavLink>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <label htmlFor="check" className="bar">
          <span className="faBars" id="bars"><FaBars/></span>
          <span className="faTimes" id="times"><FaTimes/></span>
        </label>
      </nav>
    </>
  );
}
```

Note that the this.getBackendOptions is making reference to an async function that shows the whole object for the relationship between pets - owners (a pet needs to have an owner, so getBackendOptions brings the entire owner JSON file and displays it on the column "owner" from the pets table).

```
getBackendOptions = async (newState) => {
        const {options} = this.state;
        const petsPromise = listEntity({ entity: "pets" });
        const ownersPromise = listEntity({ entity: "owners" });
        let [pet = [], owner = [] = await Promise.all([
            petsPromise,
            ownersPromise,
        ]);

        pet = pet.map((_pet, index) => ({
            value: _pet.id,
            tag: `${_pet.petName} (${_pet.petType})`,
        }));
        const newOptions = {...options, pet, owner};
          this.setState({ ...newState, options: newOptions }, () => {
            this.showEntity();
        });
    };
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you [edit] to clarify what "backend elements" are and what you are expecting to happen? What exactly is rendered when the path is `"/pets"` and what are you expecting to be rendered when the path changes to `"/owners"`? What is `this.getBackendOptions`? Can you edit to a [mcve]?

Comment: Hi, I just modified the question in order to explain further

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't quite follow what the complete code overall is doing, but I highly suspect the issue is the routed content optimization `react-router` does when the same component is rendered on more than one route by keeping it mounted and simply rerendering it with updated routing context values, i.e. any route path params, the current `location` object, etc.

A barebones trivial fix would be to assign a React key to each routed component. It *looks* like this might've been what you were trying to do with the key on the `Route` component. Move the key to the `Page` component, the component that actually remains mounted when navigating between the `"/pets"` and `"/owners"` routes.

```
const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route path="/" element={<RootLayout />}>
      <Route
        path="pets"
        element={<Page key="pets" title="Pets" entity="pets" />}
      />
      <Route
        path="owners"
        element={<Page key="owners" title="Owners" entity="owners" />}
      />
    </Route>
  )
);
```

Some might consider this a bit "hackish", and it will create (*slightly*) more work for React since it now will tear down, i.e. unmount, the previous "instance" of the `Page` component and mount a new "instance".

A more correct version/implementation would be to handle the route path change in the component lifecycle, e.g. implement the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method to run the exact same logic as `componentDidMount`, but only when the path changes. Using the `entity` prop should be sufficient here though since it changes at the same time the path does.

Example:

```
class Page extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    ....
  }

  showEntity = async (_event = null) => {
    ....
  };

  setData = () => {
    const { entity } = this.props;
    if (entity === "owners") {
      this.getBackendOptions({});
      return;
    }
    this.showEntity();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setData();
  };

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.entity !== this.props.entity) {
      this.setData();
    }
  }

  ....
```